# How to implement a callback in Node's app.get function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a working website in which I would now like to implement some logic/data analysis.

Here's the call to render my /data page:

```
app.get("/data", (req, res) => {
  const sql = "SELECT * FROM MyMoods";
  const avg = calc_data_avg();
  console.log("Average in app.get: ", avg);
    db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
          return console.error(err.message);
      }
      res.render("data", { model: rows, avg });
    });
});
```

I want to be able to display the average of a column from my database, and created this function (which I call in app.get):

```
function calc_data_avg() {
  var result;
  const sql = "SELECT AVG(mood_score) FROM MyMoods";
  db.all(sql, [], (err, avg) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
    result = avg[0]['AVG(mood_score)'];
    console.log(result);
  });
  return result;
}
```

However, the result in app.get is always undefined. I understand it's because of the asynchronicity and that I need to implement it as a callback. However at this point I can't figure out how the correct code, with callback, needs to look like.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Callback Style

If you want to use callback style, you need to use a function to wrap.

```js
function calc_data_avg(callback) {
    var result;
    const sql = "SELECT AVG(mood_score) FROM MyMoods";
    db.all(sql, [], (err, avg) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err, null)
        }
        result = avg[0]['AVG(mood_score)'];
        callback(null, result)
    });
}

app.get("/data", (req, res) => {
    calc_data_avg(function(error, avg) {
        console.log("Average in app.get: ", avg);
        const sql = "SELECT * FROM MyMoods";
        db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err.message);
            }
            res.render("data", {
                model: rows,
                avg
            });
        });
    })
});
```

If you want to wrap the "get all row", you can do this.

```js
function get_all_rows(callback) { 
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM MyMoods";
    db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err, null);
        }
        callback(null, rows);
    });
}
function calc_data_avg(callback) {
    var result;
    const sql = "SELECT AVG(mood_score) FROM MyMoods";
    db.all(sql, [], (err, avg) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err, null)
        }
        result = avg[0]['AVG(mood_score)'];
        callback(null, result)
    });
}

app.get("/data", (req, res) => {
    calc_data_avg(function(error, avg) {
        console.log("Average in app.get: ", avg);
        get_all_rows(function(error, rows) {
            res.render("data", {
                model: rows,
                avg
            });
        })
    })
});
```

### Promise style

When you wrap these two function, then you can go with promise.

```js
function get_all_rows() { 
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const sql = "SELECT * FROM MyMoods";
        db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err)
            }
            resolve(rows)
        });
    })
}
function calc_data_avg() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var result;
        const sql = "SELECT AVG(mood_score) FROM MyMoods";
        db.all(sql, [], (err, avg) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            result = avg[0]['AVG(mood_score)'];
            resolve(result);
        });
    })
}

app.get("/data", (req, res) => {
    calc_data_avg().then((avg) => {
        console.log("Average in app.get: ", avg);
        get_all_rows().then((rows) => {
            res.render("data", {
                model: rows,
                avg
            });
        })
    })
});
```

### Promise style with async-await

when you use promise style, then you can use async-await to build the function that

```js
function get_all_rows() { 
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const sql = "SELECT * FROM MyMoods";
        db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err)
            }
            resolve(rows)
        });
    })
}
function calc_data_avg() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var result;
        const sql = "SELECT AVG(mood_score) FROM MyMoods";
        db.all(sql, [], (err, avg) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            result = avg[0]['AVG(mood_score)'];
            resolve(result);
        });
    })
}

app.get("/data", async (req, res) => {
    const avg = await calc_data_avg()
    console.log("Average in app.get: ", avg);
    const rows = await get_all_rows();
    res.render("data", {
        model: rows,
        avg
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that already gives me a good idea of the solution. However, with this code I'm now missing the part where I fetch all the rows from my database. The idea is that on the /data page, I want to show how many entries there are in total, and an average, hence "SELECT * FROM MyMoods" in my code, and using a function to do the "SELECT AVG(mood_score) FROM MyMoods" part. I'm still not sure how to reconcile both with the callback/promise solutions.

Comment: okay, i think i get your point. Later i will write a new example version.

Comment: But you can try to wrap function which i did in the callback style.

Comment: @user3928933 Hey, I just add some new example. You can check it :)

Comment: Many thanks for your help! Promise style with async-await is working fine (the other methods might as well but I didn't succeed).

Comment: @user3928933 I found the bug in my code, I just fixed it. you can try other two style.

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to call `calc_data_avg` within the `db.all(...)`call. Another (better) way is to work with promises i.e. do your queries in functions that return promises and in the `GET` endpoint you would wait for all promises resolving with `Promise.all`. Let me know if I should elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! calling calc_data_avg in db.all doesn't seem to change anything, I still get an undefined. Could you please elaborate? :-) I'm currently reading about callbacks on the side, I understand the principles with simple examples but can't figure out how to do it in this case. Promises I'm not yet familiar with, going to research that as well.